# How can I change text to new text?

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm making an API called Server.js Now, what I'm trying to do is change the HTML text `({date})` turn to the actual date. Instead of changing it to the actual date it stayed as `({date})`. I'm wondering how I can fix this. Can you help me? This is my code:

```
var doc = document.toString();
var doc1 = doc.replace("\(\{date\}\)", new Date());
doc.innerHTML = "";
doc.innerHTML = doc1;
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why are you escaping parts of the string?  `"\(\{date\}\)"` should just be `"({date})"`.

Comment: And why do you need a regex capture group?

Comment: Nevermind you escaped it

Comment: Yeah I mistook it for regex as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the escaped characters. Just make it a normal string.

```
var doc1 = doc.replace("({date})", new Date());
```

EDIT: There are several ways you could possibly replace all occurrences. A simple search would reveal questions like [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

You can try a regular expression:

```
var doc1 = doc.replace(new RegExp("\\({date}\\)", 'g'), new Date());
```

Comment: To be clear, are you just trying to replace one occurrence or all occurrences?

Comment: I'm trying to do all.

Comment: Does this correctly replace the first occurrence, though?

Comment: @Judahrogan It would be more helpful to us if you explained *how* it doesn't work.  Simply saying "it doesn't work" doesn't inform us how code needs to be changed.

Comment: @Judahrogan It's been a while since we've heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: Waiting for what?